# docker-composer up error nginx: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, nginx

I created a docker-composer.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

After running docker-composer up,

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

so I ran docker-compose --verbose up -d which output this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.24.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 42, in project_from_options
    compatibility=options.get('--compatibility'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 123, in get_project
    host=host, environment=environment
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 97, in get_client
    version_info = six.iteritems(client.version())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 230, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. I'm pretty new to docker. Anyone know why it is giving me a PermissionError? 
I tried using sudo with the command as well to no avail.

This is the [tutorial](https://github.com/ucfopen/fuelphp-crash-course-docker) I've been following.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When sudo is not an option, adding the user to the `docker` group does the trick:

```
To run Docker as a non-root user, you have to add your user to the docker group.
- Create a docker group if there isn't one: $ sudo groupadd docker.
- Add your user to the docker group: $ sudo usermod -aG docker [non-root user]
- Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
```

Credits where it's due: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/run-docker-as-a-non-root-user/

Comment: I prefer `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

Answer (score 1):

In my case 'sudo' before command helped - I run

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build dev
```

instead of

```
docker-compose up -d --build dev
```

and it helped. Issue was in lack of rights.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I didn't have the docker service enabled through systemctl. 
Running `sudo systemctl enable docker` did the trick.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue.